# How can I make a timer display seconds?

Tags: python, tkinter

I read that a countdown timer could be made with time.sleep(). This is my attempt. I can print the seconds to the idle, but not to the Tkinter window. Is there a hack around it?

```py
import time; from tkinter import *

sec = 11
def start(timer):
    print(countDown(sec,timer))

def countDown(sec,timer):
    while sec >= 0:
        print(sec)
        if sec > 9:
            timer.configure(text = str(sec)) #'two digits'
        elif sec > 0:
            timer.configure(text = '0'+str(sec)) #'one digit'
        else:
            timer.configure(text = 'GAME OVER!')
        sec -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

win = Tk()
win.configure(bg='black')
header = Label(win, text="Game Timer", fg='blue', bg='black', font=('Arial Bold',14))
header.pack()
timer = Label(win, relief=SUNKEN, fg='white', bg='black', font=('Arial',14))
timer.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
btn = Button(win,text='Start', command= lambda: start(timer))
btn.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you want to simply format your time.

Comment: Mike - SMT - Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by it. Could you give me a hint, please.

Comment: There are likely dozens of questions on this site about creating clocks and timers with tkinter. Have you done any research?

Comment: @plr108 your edits had no improvement to the question. adding `Tkinter:` to the title is pointless as that is what tags are for and you added a 2nd layer of indention when the code was already formatted properly. I have rolledback the change. Please take more care in your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things we can do to improve this.

1. Instead of trying to manage the format using an if statement we can use `strftime` to format out time. This can be done for say Days, Hours, Min, Sec and so on but right now we just need Seconds.
2. You want to avoid `while` and `sleep()` while in the same thread as tkinter. This is because those 2 methods will block the main loop so you will never see the time displayed and only ever see `GAME OVER` once the while loop and sleep has completed due to both of them blocking the mainloop.
3. Write your imports on new lines and use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `*`. This will help prevent overwriting anything.
4. we can remove one of your function as it is an extra step that is not needed.
5. to manage a timed loop in tkinter we can use `after()`.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


def count_down(sec):
        if sec > 0:
            timer.configure(text=time.strftime('%S', time.gmtime(sec)))
            win.after(1000, lambda: count_down(sec-1))
        else:
            timer.configure(text='GAME OVER!')


win = tk.Tk()
win.configure(bg='black')
sec = 11

header = tk.Label(win, text="Game Timer", fg='blue', bg='black', font=('Arial Bold', 14))
timer = tk.Label(win, relief='sunken', fg='white', bg='black', font=('Arial', 14))
btn = tk.Button(win, text='Start', command=lambda: count_down(sec))

header.pack()
timer.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
btn.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very informative! Thanks for all the hints for the suggestions